# Best Practices for dealing with unbrewed files in a fresh install of homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, install, homebrew, symlink

I accidentally deleted `/usr/local/bin` which contained `brew` among other things.  I reinstalled homebrew and ran `brew prune` to get rid of broken symlinks, but when I run brew doctor, I still get the following warning:

```
$ brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
    /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
    /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
    ...
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc
Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
```

If you want to see the full list, check here: http://pastie.org/9663902

My question is, should I manually delete these files?  According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34735/how-can-i-integrate-homebrew-with-non-managed-software-in-usr-local), I can simply leave the files (or move them to a separate folder and then run `brew link <folder name>` but since that answer is three years old (and about binaries specifically), I am checking to see if there is a more correct tactic.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part they can be safely ignored unless there is a problem with additional software not installing. As per this [comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32655#issuecomment-56903456) from one of the developers. The `brew doctor` command is largely just there as a means of troubleshooting.